# How to import a file from another directory in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I have a gradle kotlin project, and I'm generating a kotlin file from a Rust project, so it ends up in a totally different place with no gradle project structure, etc.

How do I import this file into my gradle project?

It has its own package but it's a completely standalone file. This is my gradle file:

```
rootProject.name = "my_project"
include("app")
```

It's a desktop project, NOT android.

My build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm Plugin to add support for Kotlin.
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.31"

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    application
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Align versions of all Kotlin components
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))

    // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre")

    // Use the Kotlin test library.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

    // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass.set("my_project.ffi.AppKt")
}
```

Comment: Can you share also your build.gradle.kts file?

Comment: @JohannesOehm just added it

Comment: Thanks :) For my understanding: You're developing an JVM application and want to call a Rust executable from Java? Or are you generating Kotlin code from a Rust program?

Comment: I want to call the Rust application from Java, but this I already know how to do. I just don't know how to load the kotlin file

Comment: You could make your own gradle tasks, simular to what I did in another project:

frontend build.gradle.kts: 

task("webpack", Exec::class) {
    inputs.file("package-lock.json")
    inputs.dir("src")
    inputs.file("webpack.config.js")
    outputs.dir("$buildDir/js")
    commandLine("$projectDir/node_modules/.bin/webpack")
}

root build.gradle.kts:

val copyTask by tasks.creating(Copy::class) {
    from("frontend/dist")
    into("$buildDir/resources/main/static")
    dependsOn(":frontend:webpack")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        dependsOn(copyTask)
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following code to your `build.gradle.kts` should do the trick (tested with Gradle 7.3.2):

```kotlin
// TODO: replace this dummy task with the task from your Rust project which
//  generates the Kotlin source directory. Make sure that the generated
//  directory (with the Kotlin file(s)) is the task output directory.
val rustTask by tasks.registering(Copy::class) {
    // To test this, I had simply put a Kotlin file into this "somewhere"
    // directory.
    from("somewhere")
    into(temporaryDir)
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir(rustTask)
        }
    }
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        dependsOn(rustTask)
    }
}
```

So, we’re simply adding the generated sources as an additional source directory to the default `SourceSet` which is consumed by the `compileKotlin` task. In addition, we make sure that the sources are generated before `compileKotlin` runs.